# Android chat application architectures

Tags: android, chat

I have a requirement where we need to build a group chat application. This chat app will also contain multimedia messages.

As we know we can architect the chat app using GCM/FCM and XMPP Protocol. Problem with the GCM/FCM is, it cannot handle multimedia messages and XMPP is a heavy architecture.

Do we have any other servers or architectures apart from GCM/FCM and XMPP?

Thank you

Comment: _FCM_ provides multimedia

Comment: _FCM_ can send the payload of 4k max. Please help how can we send multimedia files.

Answer (score 3):

Use FCM. When you want multimedia items just **use url** of the items. FCM can send receive urls easily.

You can just point to the multimedia files where they are stored over the Hosting Servers.